# How to add Gradient color in border in react native

Tags: react-native

```html
<View
style={{
borderColor:'red'
}}
>
</View>
```

here we use borderColor for view.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install this package to [Linear-gradient](https://github.com/react-native-linear-gradient/react-native-linear-gradient) on react-native

aslo check this working-example from this [article](https://codeburst.io/linear-gradient-for-border-color-in-react-native-5bcab3eea1c9)

Comment: i need border color for topBorder:90, bottomBorder:50.